# How to use mathematical induction to prove every polynomial of degree k with a_k > 0 belongs to theta(n^k)?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

The question is as follows: Prove that every polynomial of degree k, p(n) = a_k n^k + a_k-1 n^k-1 +... + a_0 with a_k> 0, belongs to theta(n^k).

I'm unsure of where to start.

Comment: Draw n^k as a factor and establish that the other factor is Θ(1).

Answer (score 0):

To show that every polynomial of degree k is O(n^k), we must show that there exist constants n0 and c such that for n > n0, a_k n^k + a_k-1 n^k-1 + … + a_0 <= c * n^k. If we choose c = |a_k| + |a_k-1| + … + |a_0|, then it is easy to verify that the RHS must be greater than or equal to the LHS; it cannot be otherwise, since every term in the LHS corresponds to a term in the RHS which must be greater than or equal to it.

To show that every polynomial of degree k is Omega(n^k), we must show that there exist constants n0 and c such that for n > n0, a_k n^k + a_k-1 n^k-1 + … + a_0 >= c * n^k. To demonstrate this, take c = a_k / 2. Then we can subtract a_k/2 n^k from both sides to get a_k/2 n^k + a_k-1 n^k-1 + … + a_0 >= 0. This polynomial has at most k real roots; let n0 be the largest real root of the polynomial. Then, for all n > n0, the polynomial must remain either nonnegative or nonpositive. Suppose it remained nonpositive. Then a_k/2 n^k <= a_k-1 n^k-1 + … + a_0. Dividing through by n^k gives a_k/2 <= a_k-1 / n + … a_0 / n^k. The RHS of this inequality is a strictly decreasing function which approaches zero as n increases without bound; therefore, this inequality cannot be true in general. Therefore, the polynomial remains nonnegative after the largest root, n0; hence, the original polynomial is confirmed to be Omega(n^k) with c = a_k/2 and n0 equal to the largest root of the polynomial a_k/2 n^k + … + a_0.

Because every polynomial of degree is simultaneously O(n^k) and Omega(n^k), it is therefore also Theta(n^k).

Comment: I just reread the title and realized you were asking for an inductive proof. If my answer, which does not use induction, is not helpful, please let me know and I will remove it.